# Rails redirect_to not rendering

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm at a logical 'fork' in the road where a user can pick a payment plan for my service or use a 'coupon code', which they've pre-purchased.  I have the functionality for selecting the 'payment plan' working and now I'm working on the other fork in the road, but feel like I'm going about it all wrong.  I ended up copying and adapting the 'payment plan' functionality with the inclusion of `coupon_code`... so, I have a separate route if they select to use a coupon as well a separate views and controller methods.

In the end, I'll need to create a 'customer' for future payment, instead of the functionality that I have in place that creates a 'customer' and immediately charges them, hence the need for the fork in the road (i think).

Of course, I could me going about this all wrong, so please let me know if there is a better way.

Here's what I have for attempting to get the coupon code stuff working, however, it's not redirecting to the new view, even though the logs say it is, the 'POST' seems to work fine.  I'm not sure why the log shows that it's trying to render `packages/show.json.jbuilder` which I assume is the problem here:

**console log**

```html
Started POST "/packages/coupon" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-25 10:52:17 -0500
Processing by PackagesController#coupon as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "coupon_code"=>"59ee713a79b44af780c7b7c54f046570"}
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."id" = 16  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Role Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles"."id" = "roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "roles"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "roles_users"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 16]]
  Device Load (34.9ms)  SELECT  "devices".* FROM "devices"  WHERE "devices"."identifier" = '59ee713a79b44af780c7b7c54f046570'  ORDER BY "devices"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/packages/coupon
Completed 302 Found in 59ms (ActiveRecord: 36.4ms)


Started GET "/packages/coupon" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-03-25 10:52:17 -0500
Processing by PackagesController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"id"=>"coupon"}
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "users"."id" = 16  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Role Load (0.6ms)  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "roles_users" ON "roles"."id" = "roles_users"."role_id" WHERE "roles"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND "roles_users"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 16]]
  Rendered packages/show.json.jbuilder (8.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 51ms (Views: 44.8ms | ActiveRecord: 1.4ms | Solr: 0.0ms)
```

**views/packages/index.html.erb**

```html
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="couponModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="couponModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="couponModalLabel">Enter Coupon Code</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Enter your pre-purchased coupon code in the area below.</p>
        <%= form_tag('/packages/coupon', id: 'coupon_form', remote: true) do %>
          <%= text_field_tag 'coupon_code', nil, placeholder: 'Coupon Code' %>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <%= submit_tag "Submit Code", class: "btn btn-success" %>
      </div>

        <% end %>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**controllers/packages_controller.rb**

```html
  # Route for using a coupon code
  def coupon
    device = Device.where(identifier: params[:coupon_code]).first
    if !device.nil? && device.is_provisioned
      # TODO: Route to new route that just adds customer to stripe
      redirect_to controller: 'packages', action: 'coupon'
    else
      # TODO: Back to pacakge page letting them know the coupon is invalid.
      puts false
    end
  end
```

**views/packages/coupon.html.erb**

```html
<div class="row login-container column-seperation">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <h2 class="text-center">You're almost done!  You've already paid for the service, so we just need to collect your payment information for future purchases.</h2>
      <br/>
        <div class="row">
          <div align="center" class="col-md-12">
            <%= render 'coupon_form' %>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**config/routes.rb**

```
 match '/packages/coupon', to: 'packages#coupon', via: [:post, :get]
```

Comment: can i see your `packages_controller` ? You are calling as `JS`. Its `JavaScript`, look at console `Processing by PackagesController#coupon as JS`. JS will not redirect, u ll have to make it ajaxing catch then. or call as HTML to `redirect`  it.

Comment: or just remove `<%= form_tag('/packages/coupon', id: 'coupon_form', remote: true) do %>` `remote: true` part to call as HTML then it will redirect !!!

Comment: @7urkm3n what part are you looking for?  There isn't a reference to rendering as json anywhere... that's what I'm confused about.

Comment: its not Json, its JS(JavaScript). u are calling it asynchronously.

Comment: @7urkm3n removed 'remote: true', but it's still looking for the 'show' template... I need it to look for the 'coupon.html.erb' template.  Am I calling it wrong in the coupon method?

Comment: after removing `remote: true`, can u share `console log - output` ?

Comment: @7urkm3n got it working!  ended up having to change the `redirect_to` to `render`.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call asynchronously, you can use 
`remote: true`

```
<%= form_tag('/packages/coupon', id: 'coupon_form', remote: true) do %>
```

To fetch it, create file in **/packages** folder **/create.js.erb** file.

`console.log("<%= j render @package %>");`

check browser console to see fetched data.

```
$('nav').after("<div class='alert alert-success'> Package Successfully Added </div>");
$('#packages').append("<%= j render @package %>");
```